# Plot a line on 30m TF based on data from 4H timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I have horizontal lines plotted on the 4H TF, that goes from `bar_index -3` to `bar_index`.

These are working as expected, however, I would like to plot the same horizontal lines, but on the 30m TF.

I have requested the `bar_index` data through securities, like so:

```
barindex4Hour = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', bar_index)
line.new(barindex4Hour - 1, candle2Low, barindex4Hour - 2, candle2Low, width = 1)
```

But the lines aren't being plotted as I expect.

Essentially, they should cover many 30m candles (because they're 4H candles).

Is there a way to plot a horizontal line on the 30m chart, using timeframe data from the 4H chart?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

All lines are plotted on candle close.
If you are on higher TF then until that candle closes, the lines will not get the reference bar_index to plot the line.
Short answer "I do not think its possible to plot lower TF lines while using HTF candle chart"

Comment: Looking at the documentation, `bar_index` starts at zero for the first historical candle. So if I want to plot historical candle data, then this shouldn't be a problem? "Note that bar indexing starts from 0 on the first historical bar."